# Are there any useful method to pick funds?

Tags: mutual-funds, index-fund

Since there are some many funds in the market, and there are so many data, are there any methods or algorithms to pick funds to maximize the return of funds.

Comment: Obligatory Will Rogers quote: "Don’t gamble; take all your savings and buy some good stock, and hold it till it goes up, then sell it. If it don’t go up, don’t buy it.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest single factor in mutual funds of any given type appears to be the fees to maintain and operate it. Those subtract directly from your potential gains. Unless you are really convinced that the difference between the results of similar funds will exceed the difference in their costs, or there are other reasons for accepting lower real returns than you could get, look for lowest cost from an investment house you trust.

Note that this is part of why index funds -- which minimize those costs -- do as well as or better than actively managed funds when you look at real results.

Beyond that, diversify across types of investment. Pick a target profile, and rebalance between funds when your mix departs too far from those percentages (where "too far" may be 5% or so) and/or put new investments into whichever funds are furthest below their targets.

Note that in a recent interview (as part of an NPR Marketplace segment about the bet), the professional investor who bet Warren Buffet that his hand-curated investments would outperform Buffet's index fund set by a specific date next year admitted that the advice he would give most folks would be to stick with index funds.

(http://www.npr.org/2016/03/10/469897691/armed-with-an-index-fund-warren-buffett-is-on-track-to-win-hedge-fund-bet)

Comment: A link to that interview would be great. Still, a +1 answer.

Comment: @joetaxpayer: Done.